# write command to command prompt open via executing bash file

Tags: c#, plugins, visual-studio-2015, vsix

I am working on developing the visual studio plugin. As a part of it, I want to execute one bash file. This bash file opens the command prompt.
Once command prompt is open ,  we want to write / executes bunch of commands on it.

I have tried it like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("MyBash.bat");
process.WaitForExit(5000);
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo %PATH%");
```

But I can see that, it open the command prompt but fail to write command on it.
It throws the exception at the line of writing the command to it. It seems like the command prompt open from this bash file has different process id.

Please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute directly in your batch file:

Insert this to your batch:

> start cmd.exe /k "echo %PATH%"

You can also use

> /c

if you want to close the cmd After Execution

**EDIT:**

```
    Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    info.UseShellExecute = false;
    info.FileName = "mybash.bat";


    p.StartInfo = info;
    p.Start();

    using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
    {
        if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("mysql -u root -p");
            sw.WriteLine("mypassword");
            sw.WriteLine("use mydb;");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cannot edit the batch file because of our requirement. Batch file opens the command prompt and we just does not want to print the PATH variable nut need to execute multiple commands.

Comment: I edited my answer, you can try using a StreamWriter to get your result

Comment: unfortunate Not.  I have added the sleep time before we write line but still it did not work.

Comment: yes, I see. The problem is that you execute the cmd via a .bat file. If you would run it as `info.FileName = "cmd.exe";` it would work

Comment: yes you are right. but as I need to execute batch file, not sure how to get the process open by this batch file.

Comment: You can get the process by `Process[] cmd = Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd");` the problem is that you cannot redirect the input to this process...because the property `RedirectStandardInput = false`

Comment: And you need to pray that there is only one cmd running  ^^

Comment: Yes I can see that RedirectStandardInput is false. I made it as true but still it throws exception as “StandardIn has not been redirected” when try to write line

Comment: Yes, that is because you cannot set this property to true for an running process...I think the only way to solve this problem is, that you start the cmd directly without the batch file..